# I want to combine the data in column A in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please understand that I am not good at English.
Let me give you an example.

```
A
IDs
dog
cow
rabbit
goat
sheep
mouse
horse
deer
tiger
fox
lion
elephant
pig
squirrel
sloth
panda
rhinoceros
jaguar
```

There are a total of 18 animal names from A2:A19.
I'd like to make it in a specific format by tying 5 pieces together.
I want to make it in B row.

```
="{""user_ids"":"&A2&","&A3&","&A4&","&A5&","&A6&",""}"

{"user_ids":dog,cow,rabbit,goat,sheep,"}
```

It's like this.

```
="{""user_ids"":"&A2&","&A3&","&A4&","&A5&","&A6&",""}"
="{""user_ids"":"&A3&","&A4&","&A5&","&A6&","&A7&",""}"
="{""user_ids"":"&A4&","&A5&","&A6&","&A7&","&A8&",""}"
```

This is what happens when you use the auto-completion feature. What I want is to make sure it doesn't overlap.

It's like this. I want. It's a hassle to manually write every time.

```
="{""user_ids"":"&A2&","&A3&","&A4&","&A5&","&A6&",""}"
="{""user_ids"":"&A7&","&A8&","&A9&","&A10&","&A11&",""}"
="{""user_ids"":"&A12&","&A13&","&A14&","&A15&","&A16&",""}"
```

And if you do 5 each, there are 3 left at the end.
The comma should be used only once.

```
{"user_ids":panda,rhinoceros,jaguar,,,"}
```

Please help me.

Comment: please, share a sample spreadsheet, this could be easier to help you in your locale!

Comment: you should have a look to the formula INDIRECT that will allow you to return a specific range of data (with a little math to jump from 5 to 5) combine it with the formula JOIN and maybe TRANSPOSE. more details on how they work here: https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zKOcIgCWT-5NDC_aT6SKXdyopRBG0N5S-18HWc0tjcQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
=IF(A2:A="",,CONCATENATE("{""user_ids"":",ArrayFormula(IF(JOIN(" ",FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A<>""))="",,JOIN(" ,",TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SORTN({RANDARRAY(COUNTA(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ",FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A<>"")),"[[:punct:]]",""))," ")))),TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ",FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A<>"")),"[[:punct:]]",""))," ")))},5,,1,RANDBETWEEN(0,1))," Select Col2 "))))),"""}"))
```

[image]

**Explanation** *Pending*

1 - `JOIN(" ",FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A<>""))` to get only non empty cells
 and [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) them with `" "` as a delimiter.